# Image upload moderation in Jahia

Tags: jcr-sql2, jahia

Using a Jahia form to capture image uploads. Unfortunately it doesn’t seem form submissions can be directly edited in Jahia form submission dashboard. I need a way for certain users or roles to be able to mark a particular submission as approved. What’s the best way to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jahia 8, you have the possibility to customize the UI (https://academy.jahia.com/documentation/developer/jahia/8/extending-and-customizing-jahia-ui/extending-jahia-ui).

I would advise adding a hidden input in your form set to false then, thanks to a specific screen, change this value to true.

Best regards,

Comment: Thank you for your answer - a variation of this approach is what we went with.